# What do I need to have to be ready to write a Compact Framework application communicating with GPS?

Tags: compact-framework, gps, coordinates, smart-device, gps.net

Simply I am asked to write an application for a smart device (smart cell phone), which will get the GPS coordinates from the device itself.

I have no smart device at all. And I am kind of lost among questions like how can I check if the device have a gps by using the code, if it has how can I obtain them in a "standard" way, do I need to be using frameworks like GeoFrameWork?

So, may somebody list the must or most required things I need to have ready?

Answer (score 2):

Geoframeworks GPS.NET is free these days and it's pretty comprehensive so there's no point reinventing the wheel.  It's also friendly to beginners which helps.  I strongly recommend downloading it and playing with some of the sample apps.  It's a bit tricky if you don't have a physical device to play around with but it does have GPS emulation classes that you can use.

All you need is a copy of VS2008 Pro with the Smart Device SDK installed.

Comment: So basically I can even emulate a GPS as well? Which will generate some GPS coordinates?

Comment: Yes.  You just need a raw dump from a real GPS.  It's usually in a text file format known as an 'NMEA' file.

Comment: Actually, can also fake a GPS from a list of coordinates - handy for unit testing.